# VLC Time v3.2 How can I display Frames instead of ms?

Tags: vlc-media-player, time, framerate

I took a look at [Time v3.2](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154032) and it is really nice. What I would like to have is a different output of the "Timecode". It should be hh:mm:ss:ff  as in the EBU Timecodeformat
How can I change this? I am not programmer enough to make specific changes in this Lua script to work properly. I do understand some of the lines, but need to to format the out string.
I read something about [E25] but that just displays everything in Milliseconds.